# Is it possible to build and deploy SharePoint 2013/2016 solutions in Azure Devops?

Tags: 2013, 2016, solution-deployment, azure-devops

I would like to know if it is possible to develop (e.g. a solution.wsp file) for SharePoint 2013/2016 in Azure Devops and build a pipeline for automatic deployment to the farm?

Comment: Do you have sandbox solution or farm solution?

Comment: I have a variety of solutions deployed to a farm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is!

You need a combination of multiple things:

1. build pipeline for WSP generation
2. artifact where package is stored
3. instal agent on target machine (see Deployment groups)
4. release pipeline for deploying WSP

## Build pipeline

Quite straight forward - all the magic lays in argument `/t:Package` that creates our desired WSP. We need to build, package and publish.

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  projectName: '[--project--name--]'
  packageName: '[--package--title--in--lower--case--]'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/$(projectName).csproj'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/$(projectName).csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:Package /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$x64'
    configuration: 'Release'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: src
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\$(projectName).wsp'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true

- task: UniversalPackages@0
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: '[--artifact--feed--where--package--will--be--published--]'
    versionOption: 'patch'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(packageName).wsp'
```

## Release pipeline

There is no direct YAML editor here, only UI-assisted sidebar - code below is generated by Azure.. excluding PowerShell script.

Artifacts : consume universal package from artifact feed

Stages :

- create new stage
- add "Deployment group job" that targets newly created deployment group
- download universal package

```
steps:
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal download'
  inputs:
    vstsFeed: '[--your--feeed--]'
    vstsFeedPackage: '[--your--package--]'
    vstsPackageVersion: '*'
```

- run PowerShell on target machine

```
steps:
- task: PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3
  displayName: 'Run PowerShell on Target Machines'
  inputs:
    Machines: DEV
    UserName: '[--username--]'
    UserPassword: '[--password--]'
    InlineScript: |
     # create new root folder in case it does not exists
     New-Item -Path "C:\deploy" -ItemType Directory -Force
     
     function timestamp { $(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") }
     $newFolderPath = "C:\deploy\$(timestamp)"
     
     # copy package from agent to deployment folders
     New-Item -Path $newFolderPath -ItemType Directory
     Copy "C:\agent\_work\r1\a\ .. [--path--of--package--] .. \[--package--name--].wsp" $newFolderPath
     
     # run an upgrade
     Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
     Update-SPSolution -Identity [--package--name--].wsp -LiteralPath "$newFolderPath\[--package--name--].wsp" -GACDeployment -Force
     iisreset
    CommunicationProtocol: Http
```

Once all is done - create new release.

Steps above provide basic workflow for deployment - you set up multiple stages, involve unit- or ui- tests if you have any, clear deployment folder, etc. It can be improved in numerous ways and adjusted for invidual needs - PowerShell script part is the one that can be extensively extended.

Comment: Wow, this is so detailed, thank you so much! I will take some time to review this and see what progress I can make! I will mark as resolved for now but I may need to come back later with some questions. Once again, thank you so much for this lovely answer!

Comment: Sure, happy to help! :)

Comment: Hi Kristaps. Thanks a lot for this super answer!! We have been asked to implement a CI/CD for a SharePoint 2016 environment. Currently there are three envs (Dev, staging and Production that is in VM in Azure only production) Do you know if is there any blog or post that explain step by step the process of creating the pipelines, artifacts, etc to deploy the wsp solutions, powershell involved etc? Many thanks

Comment: How do you handle project references to Sharepoint libraries?

Comment: Include step "NuGet restore" in your build pipeline - it will resolve dependencies defined in your project/solution file. See my code above.